RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [91] at entry 0 and [23] at entry 1
I tried to use the following code to train my model but I get the following issue
Here's the code:
import torch
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer, AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
from datasets import load_dataset, Dataset, DatasetDict

# Load the datasets
path = "/content/train_set.csv"
path_val = "/content/dev_set.csv"
path_test = "/content/test_ur.csv"

ds_train = pd.read_csv(path)
ds_val = pd.read_csv(path_val)
ds_test = pd.read_csv(path_test)

# Drop rows with missing values
ds_train = ds_train.dropna()
ds_val = ds_val.dropna()
ds_test = ds_test.dropna()

train_df = ds_train.copy()
val_df = ds_val.copy()
test_df = ds_test.copy()

# Create a DatasetDict object
datasets = DatasetDict()

# Convert train_df to a pyarrow.Table object
train_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(train_df)
val_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(val_df)
test_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(test_df)

# Create the train dataset
datasets['train'] = Dataset(train_table)

# Create the validation and test datasets
datasets['validation'] = Dataset(val_table)
#datasets['test'] = Dataset(test_table)

# Load the pre-trained tokenizer and model
checkpoint = "t5-small"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

# Define the preprocessing function
def preprocess_function(examples):
    inputs = tokenizer(examples['Urdu'], truncation=True)
    labels = tokenizer(examples['English'], truncation=True)
    inputs['labels'] = labels['input_ids']
    return inputs

# Set the format of the input data
datasets.set_format(type="torch")

# Apply the preprocessing function to the datasets
datasets = datasets.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)

# Define the training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          # output directory
    num_train_epochs=3,              # total # of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  # batch size per device during training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=64,   # batch size for evaluation
    warmup_steps=500,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    weight_decay=0.01,               # strength of weight decay
    logging_dir='./logs',            # directory for storing logs
)

# Create the Trainer instance
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,                         # the instantiated Transformers model
    args=training_args,                  # training arguments
    train_dataset=datasets['train'],     # training dataset
    eval_dataset=datasets['validation']  # evaluation dataset
)

# Train the model
trainer.train()




The issue appears during the training
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [91] at entry 0 and [23] at entry 1

.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................;

Did you check if examples['Urdu'] and examples['English'] have the same size?

@PauloMarques Yes, they have the same size.

Please always post the full error stacktrace. Does it work with batch_size=1? You probably want to pad your input: padding="max_length" inside your preprocess_function.
